# Set background color of a tooltip inside a listbox

Tags: mfc

I tried using this code inside `Create()` witch creates the listbox that contains the items with the tooltips:

```
CToolTipCtrl *tip = GetToolTips();
tip->SetTipBkColor(RGB(90, 60, 90));
```

But it doesn't change anything. 
Is anything else I need to do ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this helps you, but I always use the Cluetip Jquery plugin. To style my Tooltips.

It makes them look much better, and you can give all tooltips title. You can also change the color of those tooltips.

http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/demo/

Comment: Thanks for replying but I don't think I can use them in MFC :)

Comment: Oops, you are right. Quite new to this site. Didn't noticed the category!

Comment: sorry How did you use this in a mfc project? is there a special version for using JQuery in MFC application ?!

Comment: @GolnazSaraji What is an MFC project? Do you mean MVC, then the answer is no, there is no special jQuery for that, you should be able to use it.